# How do I rsync distant files with restricted permissions?

Tags: ssh, permissions, rsync

I tried to `rsync` files through `ssh` with a distant 'user' that does not have the permissions to even read them.

For instance file.conf which is:

```
root:root rwxr-----
```

What is best practice for those cases?

- Assign 'user' group to the file.conf (root:user)?
- Put my user in the'root' group?
- Put 'r' to others?
- ssh with 'root'?

Comment: Perhaps describe a bit more about the use case?

Comment: Well, I'd like to make a copy a exim4.conf file or else certs and keys for TLS, and all those files are not readable for the regular user used for ssh.

Comment: I meant more generally: what is the purpose of that copied exim4.conf?

Comment: it stands into a docker volume, mounted in a container. I am syncing my local machine and my distant one in order to run some tests locally everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to ssh as root, I recommend using `tar` instead of `rsync`:

### push

```sh
[source-host ~]$ sudo tar -pzc /etc/exim4 |ssh target-host "cat > exim4.tar.gz"
[target-host ~]$ cd /etc; sudo tar -pzxf ~/exim4.tar.gz
```

This creates a compressed tar archive of the /etc/exim4 directory but instead of writing it to local disk, it is sent over an ssh connection to the remote host and saved in your (non-root) home directory as `exim4.tar.gz`. The second command should be run on that target system. Go to `/etc` and untar that archive as root.

Like `rsync -a`, `tar -p` will ensure your permissions (and owners and timestamps) are the same, though UID and GUID may be off for some accounts (e.g. perhaps some files are owned by an "exim" account, which may have a slightly different identifier on the new system). You'll have to go in and manually correct those if they exist.

### pull

This requires an extra step since you have to run `sudo` remotely without a password.

```sh
[source-host ~]$ echo "ftg ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/tar -pzc /etc/exim4" |sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers.d/tar-exim
[target-host ~]$ cd /etc; ssh ftg@source-host "sudo tar -pzc /etc/exim4" |sudo tar -pzx
```

On the source host, this allows you to run that very specific `sudo` command without a password (for security purposes, any variation in the command won't be allowed). This is permanent, so you only have to do it once (remove that line if you don't want it there forever).

The target host can then pull the config from the source host, locally creating the compressed archive, streaming it over ssh, and unarchiving it locally as root.

It's possible that the first step is unnecessary and that you can just run the `ssh` command as `ssh -t …`. The `ssh` man page describes `-t` as

> `-t`    Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute
>   arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
>   very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple `-t`
>   options force tty allocation, even if `ssh` has no local tty.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The thing is that I'd like to pull the datas, not push them.

Comment: Gotcha. Now I have a push and a pull solution. This requires sudo's `NOPASSWD` feature (though as an alternative, interactive password entry may be possible with `ssh -t`)

Comment: well done. What about assigning ftg to a 'backup' group and then chown root:backup to the folder/file to rsync?

Comment: If this is just for backing up rather than propagating, consider keeping them as tarballs and saving them to a backup directory, ending the 2nd pull command with `> /etc/backup/exim4-$(date +%Y%m%d).tgz` instead of `|sudo tar …`. As part of setup, run `sudo mkdir /etc/backup; sudo chown root:backup /etc/backup; sudo chmod 2775 /etc/backup` and the archives should be owned by root:backup upon creation. Warning, with that scheme, you'll have a new archive every time you run your backup and you'll want to clean up that directory periodically.